# Solving for n involving logarithm

Tags: logarithms

I know how to solve if the left side is just lgn, but it has an extra n. Was it correct to multiply both sides by e?

[image]

Comment: I have honestly never seen "lgn" before. What does it mean?

Comment: @TheCount Usually, $\operatorname{lg}=\log_2$.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt OK, that's what I assumed from the context. Is it more common outside the US? Or is it somewhat esoteric?

Comment: OK, I don't understand your last step. Care to explain it?

Comment: There is no solution in elementary functions for a problem such as this. You might want to look at the [Lambert W-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)

Answer (score 0):

That is not the correct way to do it.  Indeed, checking your answer into the original line, it is obvious this is false.  Instead, note the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function):

$$n\ln(n)=\ln(n)e^{\ln(n)}=10^6\ln(2)$$

$$\implies\ln(n)=W_0(10^6\ln(2))$$

> $$\large n=e^{W_0(10^6\ln(2))}$$